# Custom loss function involving gradients in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've seen that this question has been asked a few times before, but without any resolution. My problem is simple: I would like to implement a loss function which computes the MSE between the gradient of the prediction and the truth value (eventually moving on to much more complicated loss functions).

I define the following two functions:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, x):
    dydx = K.gradients(y_pred, x)
    return K.mean(K.square(dydx - y_true), axis=-1)

def my_loss_function(x):
    def gradLoss(y_true, y_pred):
        return my_loss(y_true, y_pred, x)
    return gradLoss
```

Then, in my model I call

```
model_loss = my_loss_function(x)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01),
              loss=model_loss)
```

but I receive the following error:

`ValueError: An operation has`None`for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.`

For reference, the entire code is included below. What is the proper way to implement such a loss function?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

##################################################################################
# set neural network parameters
#     \param [in] NUM_HIDDEN_NODES: neurons per hidden layer
#     \param [in] NUM_EXAMPLES:     total number of examples
#     \param [in] TRAIN_SPLIT:      proportion of examples that are for training
#     \param [in] MINI_BATCH_SIZE:  batch size for optimization step
#     \param [in] NUM_EPOCHS:       iterations for training
##################################################################################
NUM_HIDDEN_NODES = 10
NUM_EXAMPLES = 500
TRAIN_SPLIT = .8
MINI_BATCH_SIZE = 100
NUM_EPOCHS = 400


##################################################################################
# define the function to approximate
#     \param [in] x: list of inputs to evaluate function at
##################################################################################
def my_function(x):
    return np.sin(x)


##################################################################################
# generate training and test data according to TRAIN_SPLIT
#     \param [in] start:    starting point for the data
#     \param [in] end:      ending point for the data
#     \param [out] x_train: data on which the neural network will be trained on
#     \param [out] y_train: data on which the neural network will be trained on
#     \param [out] x_test:  data on which the trained neural network will be 
#                           validated
#     \param [out] y_test:  data on which the trained neural network will be 
#                           validated
##################################################################################
def create_data(start, end):
    x = np.float32(np.random.uniform(start, end, (1, NUM_EXAMPLES))).T
    y = my_function(x)

    train_size = int(NUM_EXAMPLES*TRAIN_SPLIT)
    x_train = x[:train_size]
    x_test = x[train_size:]
    y_train = my_function(x_train)
    y_test = my_function(x_test)

    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)


from keras import backend as K

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, x):
    dydx = K.gradients(y_pred, x)
    return K.mean(K.square(dydx - y_true), axis=-1)

def my_loss_function(x):
    def gradLoss(y_true, y_pred):
        return my_loss(y_true, y_pred, x)
    return gradLoss

##################################################################################
# generate the neural network model
##################################################################################
def create_model():
    x = Input(shape=(1, ))

    # hidden layers with tanh activation function
    h1 = Dense(10, activation="tanh")(x)
    h2 = Dense(10, activation="tanh")(h1)
    h3 = Dense(10, activation="tanh")(h2)

    # linear activation layer
    y = Dense(1, activation="linear")(h3)

    model = Model(x, y)

    model_loss = my_loss_function(x)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01),
                  loss=model_loss)

    return model


##################################################################################
# routine for training the neural network
#     \param [out] x_train: data on which the neural network will be trained on
#     \param [out] y_train: data on which the neural network will be trained on
#     \param [out] x_test:  data on which the trained neural network will be 
#                           validated
#     \param [out] y_test:  data on which the trained neural network will be 
#                           validated
#     \param [out] model:   the training neural network model
##################################################################################
def train(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    model = create_model()

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
              epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, 
              batch_size=MINI_BATCH_SIZE, 
              validation_data=[x_test, y_test]
              )

    return model

# generate training and test data and train the neural network
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = create_data(-2.0*math.pi, 2.0*math.pi)
model = train(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)


##################################################################################
# use the neural network model to compute the function at test data
#     \param [in] model: the trained neural network model
#     \param [in] x:     x values at which to test the trained model
##################################################################################
def predict_targets(model, x):
    return model.predict(x)


##################################################################################
# plot the exact data against the predicted data
#     \param [in] x: x data
#     \param [in] y_true: exact y data
#     \param [in] y_pred: neural network prediction
##################################################################################
def plot_predictions(x, y_true, y_pred):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x, y_true)
    plt.plot(x, y_pred)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()


# plot neural network prediction on the original training data
predictions = predict_targets(model, x_train)
indexes = list(range(len(x_train)))
indexes.sort(key=x_train.__getitem__)
x_train = list(map(x_train.__getitem__, indexes))
y_train = list(map(y_train.__getitem__, indexes))
predictions = list(map(predictions.__getitem__, indexes))
plot_predictions(x_train, y_train, predictions)


# plot neural network prediction on the validation/test data
x = np.linspace(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi, 1000)
y = my_function(x)
predictions = predict_targets(model, x)
plot_predictions(x, y, predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came across a package on [github](https://github.com/bojone/keras_adversarial_training/blob/master/adversarial_training.py) which inspired me to customize the training loop (as described in [here).](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) I have attached an example which customizes the Sequential class and adds the mean of the loss function gradient (w.r.t. input) as an additional penalty.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

class Custom(keras.Sequential):
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data        
        
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            tape.watch(x)
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

            loss_grad = tape.gradient(loss, x)
        
            loss = loss + tf.math.reduce_mean(loss_grad)
        
        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        del tape
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```